# Why aren't the results for po and NSLog the same in this case?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, debugging

I inserted NSLog() calls in my code like this:

```
NSLog(@"error message = %@", strError);
```

I'm expecting a result to be printed like the following:

```
error message = abcdefg
```

but NSLog() prints this:

```
error message = abcd
```

It's trimmed. This didn't seem right, so I typed the following command in the debug console:

```
po strError
```

The result from this is as expected:

```
abcdefg
```

Why don't I get the same result from NSLog() and `po` here? I want the full string to be printed, like for `po`, but my program uses NSLog() and is outputting the truncated string.

Why is that, and how can I fix it?

Comment: it's NSString, local variable

Comment: Then there's something you're not telling us.

Answer (score -1):

From [Technical Note TN2124](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2124/_index.html)

> print-object(PO) actually calls the debugDescription method of the
>   specified object. NSObject implements this method by calling through
>   to the description method. Thus, by default, an object's debug
>   description is the same as its description.

`NSLog` calls `description` method and `print-object(PO)` calls the `debugDescription` method. both are same.

Comment: Why are they producing different results then?

Comment: @trojanfoe -- Not for NSString.

Comment: @HotLicks Sorry?  Parag states "both are same" - if that's the case then why has the OP shown they return different results?

Comment: @trojanfoe -- Because the OP has something effed up.